# Is there a alternative for the SQL 'Nz'-function

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

In Excel (VBA) I am trying to run a query on 2 Access databases. I am comparing 2 tables from different databases and list differences between the two ('Find Unmacthed Query')
The following query runs without error.

```
SELECT x.* FROM (SELECT * FROM TBL IN 'I:\test1.mdb') x LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM TBL IN 'I:\test\test2.mdb') y ON (x.fldId = y.fldId) AND (x.fldTxt = y.fldTxt)   
WHERE (((y.fldId) Is Null))
```

The problem with it is that Null values aren't compared correctly and will end up in the final result although the records from both database tables are equal.
I figured out that this can be solved with the `Nz-function`

```
SELECT x.* FROM (SELECT * FROM TBL IN 'I:\test1.mdb') x LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM TBL IN 'I:\test\test2.mdb') y ON (Nz(x.fldId = y.fldId)) AND (Nz(x.fldTxt = y.fldTxt))  
WHERE (((y.fldId) Is Null))
```

This however works in Access, but gives me an error when trying to run it from Excel VBA
`Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Undefined function 'Nz' in expression`

I have the following libraries selected:
1- Visual Basic For Applications
2- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
3- OLE Automation
4- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
5- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
6- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
7- Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
8- Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library

**My question is:**
Can this be solved or is there an alternative to accomplish the same?

Comment: This `Nz(x.fldId = y.fldId)` doesn't look right; nz() normally takes a number or string parameter and checks if that is NULL and if so, replaces it with 0, or '', respectively, but you are passing a boolean. Did you want to match Null to Null? if so you should have used nz(x.fldId)=nz(y.fldId)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a replacement:

```vb
' Replacement for the function Application.Nz() of Access.
'
' Returns by default Empty if argument Value is Null and
' no value for argument ValueIfNull is passed.
'
' 2020-10-13. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Nz( _
    ByRef Value As Variant, _
    Optional ByRef ValueIfNull = Empty) _
    As Variant

    Dim ValueNz     As Variant

    If Not IsEmpty(Value) Then
        If IsNull(Value) Then
            ValueNz = ValueIfNull
        Else
            ValueNz = Value
        End If
    End If
        
    Nz = ValueNz
    
End Function
```